# gnuplot - change from 2d points to heatmap

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap

I am trying to convert a plot we normally do using points to a heatmap.  The data is in x,y,z format with x,y being lat / lon and z being the # of recorded instances

We currently plot using:

```
plot 'data.dat' u 1:2:3 with points pointtype 13 lc palette, \
'boundary.dat' with lines ls 1
```

I would like to be able to plot a heatmap as 3 plots:
1. base heatmap of values
2. points at maybe 50% opacity to show underlying geo path
3. line representing the boundary.

sample image:[image]
The image on the left is gnuplot, the one on the right is from qgis.  We would like gnuplot to produce something similar to the one on the right.

Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question :)

You'll need a few steps to get a proper result:

In order to get a heatmap, you must create a regular grid and interpolate your data. This can be done with `set dgrid3d`. Because you want the interpolation only for some of your data you must write the interpolation to a temporary file:

```
set dgrid3d 200,200,2
set table 'data-heatmap.dat'
splot '< tr "," " " < data.dat' using 1:2:3
unset table
unset dgrid3d
```

Usually, you can use `set datafile separator ','` to use commas as delimiters, but the temporary file `data-heatmap.dat' contains columns separated by spaces, so you must use`tr` to replace the commas with white spaces.

Then you can plot all together. A complete script might look as follows:

```
# Diverging color palette from colorbrewer2.org
set palette defined (0 '#006837', 1 '#1a9850', 2 '#66bd63',\
                     3 '#a6d96a', 4 '#d9ef8b', 5 '#ffffbf',\
                     6 '#fee08b', 7 '#fdae61', 8 '#f46d43',\
                     9 '#df3027', 10 '#a50026')
unset key
set dgrid3d 200,200,2
set table 'data-heatmap.dat'
splot '< tr "," " " < data.dat' using 1:2:3
unset table
unset dgrid3d

set autoscale fix
set xtics 0.1
plot 'data-heatmap.dat' u 1:2:3 w image,\
     '< tr "," " " < boundary.dat' w l lc rgb 'black' lw 2,\
     '< tr "," " " < data.dat' w p pt 7 ps 0.2 lc palette
```

To get a smoother interpolation, use `set dgrid3d 200,200,1` or similar. Maybe you also want to set a fixed color range with `set cbrange`.

The result with 4.6.5 is:

[image]

The dimensions of the generated grid is derived from the bounding box of the scattered data. As a hack to extend the region of interpolation you can add two dummy points on-the-fly when creating the interpolated data: one point at the upper right and one at the upper left. Later you can correct a bit for these points with `set offsets`:

```
# Diverging color palette from colorbrewer2.org
set palette defined (0 '#006837', 1 '#1a9850', 2 '#66bd63',\
                     3 '#a6d96a', 4 '#d9ef8b', 5 '#ffffbf',\
                     6 '#fee08b', 7 '#fdae61', 8 '#f46d43',\
                     9 '#df3027', 10 '#a50026')
unset key
set dgrid3d 200,200,2
set table 'data-heatmap.dat'
splot '< echo -e "\n-118.62,34.29,1\n-118.10,34.29,1" | paste -s -d "\n" data.dat - | tr "," " "' using 1:2:3
unset table
unset dgrid3d

set autoscale fix
set offsets -0.02,-0.01,-0.01,0.01
set xtics 0.1
plot 'data-heatmap.dat' u 1:2:3 w image,\
     '< tr "," " " < boundary.dat' w l lc rgb 'black' lw 2,\
     '< tr "," " " < data.dat' w p pt 7 ps 0.2 lc palette
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Is it possible to add a small amount of padding to the top and bottom so the interpolation continues north and south a few pixels?

Comment: ok, perfect.  the data is generated programmatically, so I can add a few dummy rows / columns as needed.  I also changed it to create using spaces instead of commas so the tr isn't necessary.  Thanks!